# How to destroy the instantiated bullet holes and bullet sparks prefabs in javascript

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to destroy the  instantiated  bullet holes and bullet sparks prefabs at the point of raycast hit after few seconds , here's the code i'm using to instantiate them

```
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)*100,hitShot))     {

        var rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation( Vector3.up, hitShot.normal );
    var  instantiatedExplosion : GameObject = Instantiate(
           hitParticles, hitShot.point, rotation );



         var rotation1 = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward,hitShot.normal);
         var instantiatedHole: GameObject =Instantiate (bulletHoles,hitShot.point,rotation1);

        }
```

Comment: What approaches have you attempted at this point? Have you considered adding a script to them that counts down once the item is instantiated, then destroys or disables them once the timer reaches 0?

Comment: @Serlite this whole working is being implemented in the gunfire script where the prefabs are referenced in the inspector and then instantiated as clones whenever Fire1 is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used Unity with JavaScript. However, I think the APIs give you the same method for destruction as for C#, so try this:

```
Destroy(bulletHole, time);//public static void Destroy(Object obj, float t = 0.0F);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html

I suppose you are new in Unity, normally you try to not destroy GameObjects like bullets, bullet holes, bullet sparkles etc. (or any gameObject you can reuse) because you can reuse them saving a lot of performance. See [Object Pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling)